# Declaring a TypeScript Namespace as Global

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm building a TypeScript type declaration (.d.ts) file for as custom, proprietary server-side JavaScript framework. The framework has several namespaces which are imported into the global namespace for convenience. This relationship is similar to the relationship between the global namespace and the variables of the window object in the browser. It looks something like this.

```
namespace foo.bar { 
    export function baz() { //... }
}

baz(); //The function is loaded into global...
foo.bar.baz(); //But it also exists in the namespace
```

The namespaces that are imported into global are complex with many classes and many nested namespaces. Is there any way to express this relationship between a namespace and the global namespace in a type declaration file without duplicating declarations? This would allow me to avoid duplicating thousands ambient declarations.

Comment: I would suggest to just take a look on how typings for jquery and angular 1 look like. I'm also not sure if the duplication into global for convenience isn't the first think you should revise, as this only will cause trouble. But I'm really interested in the answers :D

Comment: It's not for my convenience. The framework developers designed the framework to load certain namespaces into global. I have no control over that. I'm merely trying to reflect their design decisions into the type declaration file